# MongoDB update array of documents with new array of documents

Tags: javascript, mongodb

It is possible to insert an array of objects, but not possible to update them. You have to remove them and then insert them. I don't want to have to remove and then insert them, because if the remove goes well but then the insert has an error, the data is lost. How can I update an array (all documents) in a collection, properly?

Inserting array of documents:

```
collection.insert(arrToInsert, function(err, results){
    console.log(results.ops);
});
```

Updating inserted array (not good):

```
collection.remove({}, function(err){
    collection.insert(arrUpdated, function(err, result) {
        console.log(results.ops);
    });
});
```

I have tried using collection.update but this does not allow an array.

edit:
For example:
Insert this array:

```
[
    {_id:0,name:"Harry"},
    {_id:1,name:"Jacob"},
    {_id:2,name:"Bob"}
]
```

and then, change it to this:

```
[
    {_id:0,name:"Dennis"},
    {_id:1,name:"Peter"},
    {_id:2,name:"Ghandi"}
]
```

My actual case is a bit more complicated, because the array has another key/value pair, and can be changed in many ways.

Comment: Really hard to tell what you are doing because your question is not phrased with a clear example. You perhaps mean multiple `.update()` operations with `.bulkWrite()`. It's generally better to "show us" rather than talk about something you don't actually show, which is what your question presently does. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the help center which gives you tips on how you structure a question so people understand what you mean and how to solve it.

Comment: but with .bulkWrite each object in the array must have a key e.g. {insertOne : { "document" :_id:0,name:"Dennis"} ... which makes no sense and I cannot iterate each object in the array with bulkWrite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean [`.bulkWrite()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Collection.html#bulkWrite), which allows multiple update operations ( Insert/Update/Remove) on the same collection in a single batch request. It actually is what modern drivers really call when either `.insert()` or `.insertMany()` is called with an array of documents.

Your new update would be:

```
var arrToUpdate = [
    {_id:0,name:"Dennis"},
    {_id:1,name:"Peter"},
    {_id:2,name:"Ghandi"}
];

collection.bulkWrite(
  arrToUpdate.map( d => ({
    "replaceOne": {
      "filter": { "_id": d._id },
      "replacement": d
    }
  })),
  function(err,result) {
    console.log(result)
  }
)
```

Where [`replaceOne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#replaceone) is essentially an "update" without using any modifiers such as `$set`.

The point is that just like `.insert()` with an array or `.insertMany()`, the database receives only **one** request and response, but there are multiple operations in that request.

Comment: thanks, that looks right. although it has a syntax error, bad brackets?

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell Yes, missing a bracket. That's what I get for typing directly into the answer.

Comment: I actually had to use collection.find({}) to get the document because the result didn't return it.

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell It is not meant to return it. The only reason `insertMany()` does is because you actually supplied the document to insert, so it just maps the assigned `_id` values ( if none was supplied ) onto the documents you provide. No form up "update" aside from the `.findAndModify()` variants "return the document". For which I might add, since **you** are supplying the documents then what possible use is a `.find()`? You already know what you sent.

Comment: next problem... if I change the array to an empty array [] it has an error."Invalid Operation, no operations specified"

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell If you have a new question then [Ask a new Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), which is what you do here. It's really not that hard if you think for a minute, becuase you pretty much should be able to tell if an array is empty or not.